# Illegal Data at Start of File ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to read an XML file using the ElementTree library in Python. I have simplified my XML file all the way down to a single root:

```
<ssf>
</ssf>
```

The extension for the file is ".ssf"

When I try to read the file using ET.parse(file), I am getting the following error:

> Exception: Syntax error at line 1: illegal data at start of file

I am not sure what I am missing.

Code:

```
def ssf(ssf_path):
    tree = ET.parse(ssf_path);
    root = tree.getroot();
```

Comment: Try deleting the file and recreating it and then add this xml back into it. I am guessing you have some kind of invisible element at the first line.

Comment: @AnandSKumar Tried that just now, and I am getting the same error.

Comment: Try openning file using `open()` , and then printing each line (by iterating over the openned file), and then update the question with what was printed. (Do this in python)

Comment: @AnandSKumar I ran the xml with an XML Validator (http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp) and it succeeded.

Comment: It did not cause any issue for me either, I am suspecting the actual issue is inside the file.

Comment: @AnandSKumar I read the file, and there seemed to be extra lines. So, I removed the spaces and made it an inline tag (<ssf />). This also gave me the same error.

Comment: And now when you read the file there is nothing other than `<ssf>\n</ssf>` ?

Comment: Can you just do the printing I asked you before and update the result in the question? I would like to check it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the illegal data at the start of file was [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

You didn't mention which python you are using. Some versions of python(in my case Ironpyhton) don't open text files as unicode by default. So, if your file was saved as a unicode file (with BOM at the beginning), `open` function reads the BOM as some character, not a flag to detect encoding. this way, you end up with an invalid xml string!

Here is one way to solve the problem: you open and read the file into a string yourself and then parse that string:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree
import io

path = '.\\file.ssf'
txt = ''
with io.open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as o:
    txt = o.read()
root = xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(txt)
```